# How to solve my simple geometric task?

Tags: geometry, vector-graphics

It seems I completely forgot geometry :-( It looks like a simple. I need it for my flash game.

I drawn it in Carmetal program:
[image]

I need coordinates of C(x,y). Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You can stick with simple trig...

[image]

Here, the blue line length is (By - Ay). So the angle at B is `acos((By - Ay) / AB)`. Subtracting that angle from the angle ABC, you find the angle at B in the larger triangle. Knowing the length BC and that angle, you can calculate the length of the brown line with

```
l1 = BC/sin(small_angle)
```

Similarly, the length of the blue and red lines together is

```
l2 = BC/cos(small_angle)
```

And C is (Bx + l1, By - l2).

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity you _could_ identify l1,l2 and small_angle on your drawing